# Python Ruler Sequence Generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have been struggling for a long time to figure how to define a generator function of a ruler sequence in Python, that follows the rules that the first number of the sequence (starting with 1) shows up once, the next two numbers will show up twice, next three numbers will show up three times, etc.

So what I am trying to get is 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 etc.

I understand that the way to do this is to have two separate count generators (itertools.count(1)) and then for every number in one generator yield number from the other generator:

```
def rul():
    num = itertools.count(1) 
    repeator = itertools.count(1)
    for x in range(next(repeator)):
        yield from num
```

But if I hit next() on this function, I get back just the regular 1,2,3,4.. sequence...

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about regular old python with no itertools?

```
def ruler():
    counter = 1
    n = 1
    while True:
        for i in range(counter):
            for j in range(counter):
                yield n
            n += 1
        counter += 1
```

in my humble opinion this is the clearest and most straighforward solution for these types of situations

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns first number once, second twice, third three times etc. which is not the solution to the problem, as we need first once, next two numbers twice, next three numbers three times etc.

Comment: you're right, changed - but im honestly baffled by that response since it's easy to change that from here... actually wait that's not right yet lmao

Comment: Thank you for the change! Almost there but I am not sure if there is an easy solution without using itertools tbh. This sequence is not the solution either, as it is supposed to return first number once, next TWO numbers TWICE and next THREE number THREE times

Comment: yeah i reread the output... honestly would help if you gave a bigger output as an example but here you go this one works

Comment: Looks less clever now, but still a good one!

Answer (score 1):

How about [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)?

```
import itertools

def ruler():
    num = rep_count = 0
    while True:
       rep_count += 1
       for i in range(rep_count):
           num += 1
           yield from itertools.repeat(num, rep_count)
```

Comment: I don't think this makes 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5, etc but 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4, instead

Comment: @RichardKYu Oh sorry I misread the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain such a generator without writing your own function using `count()` and `repeat()` from itertools:

```
from itertools import repeat,count

i   = count(1,1)
rul = (n for r in count(1,1) for _ in range(r) for n in repeat(next(i),r))

for n in rul: print(n, end = " ")

# 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 11 11 ...
```

Comment: I like this! Thanks Alain:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go all in on `itertools`, you'll need `count`, `repeat`, and `chain`.

You can group the numbers in your sequence as follows, with
each group corresponding to a single instance of `repeat`:

```
1          # repeat(1, 1)
2 2        # repeat(2, 2)
3 3        # repeat(3, 2)
4 4 4      # repeat(4, 3)
5 5 5      # repeat(5, 3)
6 6 6      # repeat(6, 3)
7 7 7 7    # repeat(7, 4)
...
```

So we can define `ruler_numbers = chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, col1, col2))`, as long as we can define `col1` and `col2` appropriately.

`col1` is easy: it's just `count(1)`.

`col2` is not much more complicated; we can group them similarly to the original seqeunce:

```
1         # repeat(1, 1)
2 2       # repeat(2, 2)
3 3 3     # repeat(3, 3)
4 4 4 4   # repeat(4, 4)
...
```

which we can also generate using `chain.from_iterable` and `map`:
`chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, count(1), count(1)))`.

In the end, we get our final result in our best attempt at writing Lisp in Python :)

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, count
ruler_numbers = chain.from_iterable(
                  map(repeat, 
                      count(1),
                      chain.from_iterable(
                        map(repeat,
                            count(1),
                            count(1)))))
```

or if you want to clean it up a bit with a helper function:

```
def concatmap(f, *xs):
    return chain.from_iterable(map(f, *xs))

ruler_numbers = concatmap(repeat, 
                          count(1),
                          concatmap(repeat,
                                    count(1),
                                    count(1)))
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution! Thanks:)